# Parameter returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am trying to write a function that identifies if a word is an isogram or not. This is what I have done so far:

```js
function isIsogram(word) {
  var result;
  var counter = 0;
  var dubs = 0;

  if (word.length === 0) {
    result = false;
  } else {

    var lower = word.toLowerCase();
    var array = Array.from(lower);

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      counter++;

      for (j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {

        if (array[i] === array[j]) {

          dubs++;

        }
      }
    }
    if ((counter > 0) && (dubs === 0)) {

      result = true;

    } else if ((counter > 0) && (dubs > 0)) {

      result = false;
    }
  }
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

isIsogram("word");
```

When I run the above code in my browser's javascript console, it works pretty well. But when I post it onto the environment where I am being tested, it gives an error that "word" (the parameter) is undefined.

I even tried hard coding a parameter by declaring a string value for word outside the function, it still said undefined. What am i not doing right?

Comment: What's wrong in your code? Accept the edit, you will see it's working.

Comment: Please provide information of environment where you are testing.

Comment: Thank you for the edit suggestion, though I have tried that too.

The environment is qualified.io

Comment: I did the same thing in `qualified.io` and it's working.

Comment: Check this - https://ibb.co/nsu2Cm

Comment: Thank you Jardosh, I just did. I really don't know the reason for the error. This runs smoothly in my browser.

Comment: Is something stripping out the quotes on the "word" when you put it /post it somewhere else?

Comment: Not related but you might do `var result = false;` as a default.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. Already got a an answer. I just have to change my first `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work as far as I can see.
Can you provide information about how you call your function `isIsogramm('teststring');`?

https://jsfiddle.net/TobiObeck/z15eos81/

Comment: Thank you Tobi. I am running just as I have pasted it here. Though, mine is an assessment. I think behind the scene the platform runs the function with three different parameters as a way to test that the function performs the task just as required.

Comment: Maybe one of the inputs is actually a function call without any parameter. Like `isIsogram();` Than you should add sth. like `if(!word) return false;` to your code, because the length property is undefined if the word parameter is null. Also consider numbers as an input, because of `toLowerCase();`

Comment: Tobi, I just ran it exactly how you ran it on jsfiddle. In the sampleTest environment, it gave no errors. BUt when I click to submit my solution, it still gives the "word is not defined" error message. I need help please...

Comment: Did you try the suggestions from my last comment?

Comment: You are an angel that came for the rescue! It beats my imagination how you came up with this thought! `if(!word) return false;` was just the solution! I changed the first `if` statement to your suggestion above and boooom!!! it worked. Thank you very very very much.

Comment: Yes brother! I did and have made my comment. Thank you so so much.